# Remove existing Go installation before updating?

Tags: windows, go, installation

I am using windows 10.

In [this link](https://golang.org/doc/install?download=go1.11.windows-amd64.msi) is it been asked to remove current Go installation before updating to new version. The current installation folder is something like: `C:\Go` . And it is [been asked](https://golang.org/doc/install?download=go1.11.windows-amd64.msi#uninstall) to remove this folder first before installing the latest version.

But I already have my projects under `C:\Go\src`. So I can't afford to delete it just like that. Not sure what I am missing. I have never updated Go before, so this is new to me. Thanks.

Comment: you are not supposed to have your src files in `C:\Go` folder, it was supposed to be in your home directory.

Comment: I don't see where in the instructions it says you have to remove your existing Go directory before updating. Could you point that out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Those same instructions tell you to](https://golang.org/doc/install?download#testing)...

> Create your workspace directory, `%USERPROFILE%\go`. (If you'd like to use a different directory, you will need to set the GOPATH environment variable.)
>
> C:> cd %USERPROFILE%\go\src\hello
>   C:\Users\Gopher\go\src\hello> go build

So your `src` directory should not be in `C:\Go\src` but `%USERPROFILE%\go\src\` (that is in your home directory). If you've been using `C:\Go\src`, move it to `%USERPROFILE%\go\src\` and use that going forward.

---

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, I had understood it wrong before.